# Has anyone established an upper bound for the least integer $k$ such that infinitely many primes have at most $k$ ones in their binary representation?

Tags: prime-numbers, binary, constants

Has anyone established an upper bound for the least integer $k$ such that infinitely many primes have at most $k$ ones in their binary representation?

$2$ is the only prime with $1$ one, the Fermat primes are the only primes with $2$ ones, for $3$ ones we want primes of the form $2^a+2^b+1$ with $a>b$, so

$2^a+2^b+1=2^b(2^{a-b}+1)+1$, then

$2^a+2^b+2^c+1=2^c(2^{b-c}(2^{a-b}+1)+1)+1$,

and so on.

This would be a start if one hoped for the existence of infinitely many Fermat primes.

Edit: [This paper](http://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/drmota/DMRcomp2.pdf) proves that for all sufficiently large $t$ we can find a prime with *exactly* $t$ ones in their binary representation.

Comment: This seems to be open; see the related question [Are There Primes of Every Hamming Weight? - MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22629/are-there-primes-of-every-hamming-weight)

Comment: Hope for _infinitely many_ Fermat primes? I would be happy with just six of them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm perfectly happy with five, all I hope for is _some_ positive integer $k$. I don't think any of the primes for $k>2$ have a name, which is why I cited the possibility of infinity many Fermat primes.

Comment: @ChrisCulter A reference from that thread actually proves the existence of $k$.

Comment: @JaycobColeman That's a really interesting paper! I might be reading it wrong, but I don't think it proves the desired result. In Theorem 1.1, it's not immediately obvious how the estimate behaves for fixed $k$ (in their notation) and increasing $x$. At the end of the first section, the authors mention that their method doesn't help to bound tail distributions that are even broader than the count you're looking for.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I don't really follow the paper, but one of the comments and the accepted answer for the other question imply that the paper answers their question for sufficiently large digit sums, which would imply the existence of $k$.

Comment: @JaycobColeman I think that comment means that there exists at least one such prime for all sufficiently large $n$, not that there are infinitely many such primes.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Perhaps I was a bit confused. The pigeonhole principle implies that infinitely many primes can have binary digit sum $\leq k$ if only if there exists $n\leq k$ such that infinitely many primes have binary digit sum $n$. I suppose I got a little turned around, as the paper actually implies the binary digit sums of primes grow arbitrarily large.